# I'm getting errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, kotlin, compiler-errors

I'm new in Android Studio and i am getting errors in Android Studio. How can I fix this?

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30){
            if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
                Intent getpermission = new Intent();
                getpermission.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(getpermission);
            }
        }
}
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btNJh.png)

Comment: You need to bump up the API level. In your Gradle build file there should be a two lines, `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`, make sure that these are set to at least 30. You might have to download the newer SDKs as well, but I believe Android Studio will prompt you to do so if you change the api level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the classes you are using in your code,

For e.g. if you want to use intent then import it like so:

Add this line in your import statements

```java
import android.content.Intent;
```

or else you can just hover over the error in your code and click on "Import class"